# What is the difference between "type" and "subtype" keywords?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In some PL/SQL example codes, I noticed both usages of `type` and `subtype` keywords, each time to declare a custom type (similar to the `typedef` keyword in C, for example).

It seems to me that their usages are interchangeable: what are their differences?

Comment: The [%TYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/type_attribute.htm#LNPLS01352) attribute lets you declare a constant, variable, field, or parameter to be of the same data type a previously declared variable, field, record, nested table, or database column. For the other hand, a [SUBTYPE](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/oracle/pl-sql-subtypes/) does not introduce a new type; rather, it places an optional constraint on its base type. Subtypes can be either constrained or unconstrained. Examples of unconstrained subtypes are: FLOAT for NUMBER and CHARACTER for CHAR.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you try to declare a type of a base data type with a more specific precision/scale (or constrain it to be `NOT NULL`) like this:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE int IS NUMBER(38,0);
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

Then it will not work and you get the exception:

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 15: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NUMBER" when expecting one of the following: ( array new range record varray char_base number_base decimal date_base clob_base blob_base bfile_base table ref fixed varying sparse The symbol "range" was substituted for "NUMBER" to continue.

Instead you want to use the `SUBTYPE` keyword:

```
DECLARE
  SUBTYPE int IS NUMBER(38,0);
  SUBTYPE intn IS NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

For example - [A previous question where an answer was to use a `SUBTYPE` to constrain the data to specific precision and scale.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47865212/1509264)

---

Also consider the following declarations:

1. ```
   TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER(38,0);
   ```
2. ```
   TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL;
   ```
3. ```
   SUBTYPE integern IS NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL;
   TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF integern;
   ```
4. ```
   TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER(38,0);
   SUBTYPE intlistn IS intlist NOT NULL;
   ```

For (1), the list can be `NULL` and the elements of the list can be `NULL`:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER(38,0);
  list intlist := NULL;
BEGIN
  list := intlist( 1, 2, NULL, 4 );
END;
/
```

(2) and (3) are equivalent - the list can be `NULL` but any elements contained in the list must be `NOT NULL`.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL;

  -- This works:
  list intlist := NULL;
BEGIN
  -- This also works:
  list := intlist( 1, 2, 3, 4 );

  -- But this will raise an exception
  -- list := intlist( 1, 2, NULL, 4 );
END;
/
```

To enforce that the list cannot be `NULL` you need to declare a `SUBTYPE` and enforce the constraint on that as per `intlistn` in snippet (4).

```
DECLARE
  TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER(38,0);
  SUBTYPE intlistn IS intlist NOT NULL;

  -- This works as the list is NOT NULL (even though an element of the list is)
  list intlistn := intlist( 1, 2, NULL, 4 );
BEGIN
  -- This does not works as the SUBTYPE constraint prevents it:
  -- list := NULL;
END;
/
```